# Sums of primes modulo a compoosite

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, intuition

Let $\text{Prime}(x)$ be the $x$th prime, so $\text{Prime}(1) = 2$.  My question is regarding sums modulo the product of the first $n$ primes, i.e. $\bmod Q$ with $Q = \prod_{k=1}^n{\text{Prime}(k)}$.

How many primes $p_i$ with $\text{Prime}(n) < p_i < Q$ do we need to sum to any number less than $Q$, modulo $Q$?.

**EXAMPLES**

For example, modulo $Q = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$, if we take $n=2$ primes, we can get $14$ by adding $p_1=7$ plus $p_2=7$, i.e. $7+7=14$.  We can get $18$ by adding $7+11$.   We can get $28$ by adding $29+29 \bmod 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 = 28$.

I'm wondering how many primes we need to be able to sum to any number modulo $Q$.  I conjecture that we may only need up to 3 primes, to be able to use 1, 2, or 3 primes to sum to a given number.

Comment: Wouldn't that be equivalent to the Goldblach conjecture, since any odd number $\ge 5$ is an even number plus $3$?

Comment: @GabrielBurns:  I didn't previously remember the Goldbach conjecture, but yes, it is equivalent, except that we're doing it modulo $Q$.  So I guess this can't be solved, yet :-(

Comment: @GabrielBurns:  I wonder if there is a weaker version that is known to be true, like being able to use up to 5 primes, or some larger number...

Comment: from Wikipedia: "currently, the best known result is due to Olivier Ramaré, who in 1995 showed that every even number n  ≥ 4 is in fact the sum of at most six primes."

Comment: @GabrielBurns:  Hmm... I wonder if we can find something that works modulo $Q$, with the conditions I list above (mainly that we cannot use the first $n$ primes)

Comment: That seems harder.  Primes become less dense as we move up the number line.  It seems like the lower-valued primes would be critical in providing the necessary coverage.  That's just my intuition, though.  Maybe the modular nature of the problem could help with that.

Comment: To be honest, I had missed the part where you required $\text{Prime}(n)<p_i <Q$.  I guess this isn't really Goldblach-equivalent at all, though it's certainly a closely related concept.

Comment: @GabrielBurns:  If it's necessary, I would accept an answer that allows for up to $\text{Prime}(n)$ different numbers (as opposed to 4).

Comment: Well, you're not going to get an answer from me, I'm afraid.  I know better than to even attempt to solve this one.  Wish you luck, though.

Comment: The 3 primes version of this problem is easily implied by Goldbach's conjecture, and in turn it implies a weaker form of Goldbach that for every $k<Q-2$ either $k$ or $k+Q$ is the sum of two primes $<Q$.  Morally this doesn't seem any easier than Goldbach: it would mean the exceptional set for Goldbach, while not necessarily empty, doesn't contain any differences that are primorials (of a certain size).

Comment: @ErickWong:  So, I'm wondering then, if Olivier Ramaré's work on proving every even number $> 3$ is the sum of at most 6 primes would imply this problem is true for like $n=10$ or so...  I would accept an answer that could show this.